# Accessing a class inside a non-existing class

Tags: java

How does this work?

EDIT: Being static is not a good explanation, because I can use non-static methods and it will all work. Updated the code to reflect that.

I have this in a file called Foo.java:

```
// This is in the Foo.java file
class Test {
    public void printSomething() {
        System.out.println("In Foo.Test");
    }
};
```

and this in a file called Caller.java:

```
// This goes in the Caller.java file
public class Caller {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.printSomething();
    }
}
```

I can execute my Caller and it will print `In Foo.Test`. How can this not be a compilation problem? I don't even have a `Foo` class created. I don't even have to define `Foo.Test` in the `Caller`.

This is on Eclipse Luna, Java8.

Comment: When you compile Foo.java it creates the Test.class file.  You could then delete any Foo.class file and the code would still run.

Comment: You confuse class Foo in its own file with the class Test in the same file . . .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java is weird like that. You could have a file without any lines of code and it would still compile. Go on try it.

Now, I think you are confusing Test with Foo.Test (I understand, it's Friday).

Intrinsically what you defined is this:

```
public class Foo {} // this is by default, but don't try to use it because you didn't define the scope
class Test {}
```

And your perplexity is "OMG, `Test` is the impure offspring of a non-existing class!!!", because you were expecting something like

```
public class Foo {
    class Test {}
}
```

This has nothing to do with a method being static. It is about quirkiness in the `javac`.

Happy Friday everyone! Time for happy hour.

Answer (score 1):

A java file could contain single **public** class, but it could have as much non-public classes (package-local in your case) as you wanted.

`Foo.Test` is for inner classes. The one you declared is [top level type.](https://blogs.oracle.com/darcy/entry/nested_inner_member_and_top)

Answer (score 1):

The `main`-Method of the `Foo.java` is declared static

calling static methods works without creating a object of the class.

E.g you can create following Method in `Foo.java`

```
class Test {
    public static void test(String test) {
        System.out.println(test);
    }
};
```

Now you can call `Test.test("No object will be created");` and there will be NO instance of `Test`